# Tableau combination chart to interact with a "fake" target numbers?

Tags: combinations, tableau-api, calculated-field, dummy-data

I am trying to create a combination chart with the actual numbers as the bars & the "fake" target as the line. The reason why I call it the "fake" target is because the targets are not in the data. I have them as numbers but I am struggling to actually combine them with the actual data.

I have attached an image from Google images of what I am trying to accomplish.

What calculated fields should I use to create the "fake" numbers & have them interact with the "real" actual data?

[image: Tableau screenshot]

Comment: could you please provide a sample of your data, both for actual and fake numbers?

Comment: @Fabio Fantoni Yes, This is similar to how I have the quarters in Tableau. Actuals:
FY2020 Q1: 202
FY2020 Q2: 173
FY2020 Q3: 258
FY2020 Q4: 97

Fake Target numbers:
Q1: 246
Q2: 154
Q3: 322
Q4: 156

Comment: Are those 2 separate data source?
Do they match just for quarters?

Comment: @Fabio Fantoni Yes, they are 2 separate data sources & they only match in the quarters

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to assign the target numbers against a date - you probably already have this in your spreadsheet (or whatever you're using to store these).

Copy the target numbers with dates into your Tableau workbook. Blend this new data source to your actual numbers, blending on the date fields.

Then build your bar chart, bring in the targets from your pasted secondary source and make sure the "chain" is orange in the dimension list, to show the blend is active.

Comment: I have tried this with quarters & have tried to create a relationship between the 2 (actual & fake numbers) but when I do this, all I get is a double actual. Is there a specific way I should have the fake excel data laid out? I have it as quarters (in their own columns) & then each fake number under each quarter. When pulled to Tableau, it will show each Quarter (Q1, Q2, Q3 & Q4) in the measure values as their own separate pill

Comment: Lay it out with 2 columns; Date and Target. Blend on the Date to your actuals data source

Comment: I just edited my excel date data to match how it looks in the actual data (& not just how I converted it to look in Tableau) & it finally works! Thank you for your help with this :)